STRING_SPLIT and ROW_NUMBER() - maintaining order
I have a requirement to split a string based on a delimiter and to pull the values based on their ordinals. As I am on SQL Server 2019, I cannot use String_Split with ordinal enabled. Trying to replicate the same functionality using below STRING_SPLIT and Row_Number() query.
select *, row_number() over(order by (select null)) as seq
from (
    SELECT *
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(CurrentPath, '/') where value <> ''
) t

My question is, when using select null along with order by clause and string_split, will the order of values be deterministic? I need to preserve the order in which values are returned by string_split function. Any pointers?

will the order of values be deterministic? - no.

@YitzhakKhabinsky the OP did all of the above. This is a known issue with SQL Server 2019 and the answer is unfortunately, You're out of luck

The only way to ensure order is by using an order by clause. It will most likely be consistent most of the time but not guaranteed. That was the biggest swing and a miss by the sql server team in a long time. Fortunately they fixed it in 2022 but that doesn't help you currently.

This is a common question but all the answers show tricks that work in very specific cases. If the data can be converted to JSON, OPENJSON can be used. If the data can be parsed as a hierarchyID, you can get the values by level but not all of them at once.

My biggest frustration with that miss, @SeanLange, is that it took them 6 years to address, despite how quick the community was to tell them "we need this!" after the function was announced in 2015/2016.

Anyone get the "impression" MS is more interested in PostgreSQL these days? They just announced REGEXP_SUB for Azure SQL. Along with all those super important features of SQL Server 2022 like ..... ordered STRING_SPLIT ?

Since you are 2019, you could use a bit of JSON.
Here [key] is your sequence
Example
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[CurrentPath] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'aa\bb\cc')
,(2,'aa\bb\cc\dd')
 
Select A.ID
      ,B.[key]
      ,B.[value]
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply OpenJSON( '["'+replace([CurrentPath],'\','","')+'"]' ) B

Results
ID  key     value
1   0       aa
1   1       bb
1   2       cc
2   0       aa
2   1       bb
2   2       cc
2   3       dd

